# Query between two dynamic dates and times

Tags: google-sheets

```
B1 = 3/22/2024 12:30:00 ; 
Options!F18 = 3/22/2024 6:00:00 ; 
Options!G18 = 3/23/2024 3:00:00
```

This code allows the query to come through if I adjust the time to outside the parameters.

```
        =query('Form Responses'!A2:AJ,"select * where B > datetime '"&TEXT(Options!$F$18,"yyyy- 
        mm-dd hh:mm:ss")&"' and B <= datetime '"&TEXT(Options!$G$18,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")&"'",1)
```

This code returns an empty when it should be correct.

```
        =QUERY('Form Responses'!A2:AJ, "select * where B >= date '"&TEXT(Options!F18, "yyyy-mm- 
        dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(Options!G18, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: *Can you check on the unwanted space in the midst of this part here `yyyy-mm-dd`*

Comment: @Dave Your question is not clear about what you want to achieve from this? Can you please elaborate?